# Installing .net 2.0 SDK on Windows 8

Tags: .net, sdk, windows-8, failed-installation

Has anybody been successful in installing the .NET 2.0 SDK ([x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19988) or [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15354)) on Windows 8 x64?

I have previously installed it without problem on all previous versions of Windows (I last installed both the x86 and x64 versions on Windows 7 x64 a couple of months ago) but I cannot get it to install on Windows 8 x64.

I know it is old now, but it is the only way that I know of to get the .NET Framework configuration add-ins installed and, though I know that CASPOL does the same I still prefer to be able to see the graphical representation when trying to work out custom assembly permissions and it is still very useful for generating assembly permission installers.

Comment: The link to x64 above returns "We're sorry, this download is no longer available."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I have found my own solution.

You need to start by downloading the installer(s) to a Windows 7 machine.

Once downloaded, I renamed each of the setup.exe files to represent what they were. As such, the x86 version was renamed as setup.net20.sdk.x86.exe and the x64 version as setup.net20.sdk.x64.exe.

Now, open a command prompt in the folder where you downloaded (and optionally renamed) the setup executables and run the following...

- setup.net20.sdk.x86.exe /t:"C:\net20sdk86" /c
- setup.net20.sdk.x64.exe /t:"C:\net20sdk64" /c

Obviously if you choose not to rename the downloaded files you will have to modify the command accordingly.

Finally, copy the folders C:\net20sdk86 and C:\net20sdk64 to your windows 8 machine and then run install.exe from the C:\net20sdk86 and then (assuming you are 64bit) C:\net20sdk64. Note you should run each of the installers within these folders with administrative privileges (right click, "Run as administrator").

The configuration wizards you seek will then show up on the start screen. If they are not there, open the charms menu (from the start screen), select Settings and then Tiles and ensure that "Show administrative tools" is enabled.

Voila!

Comment: Just extract the setup.exe as per @billious solution. Good that you got it working, however, extracting setup.exe is *much* simpler.

Comment: The unzip answer is simpler but it requires third party software (that 99% of people already have) while this answer will work with any vanilla windows install.

Answer (score 80):

I also managed to do it, but by using WinRAR to extract the files from the original setup.exe file I downloaded. When I ran "install.exe" from the extracted files, I was able to install the SDK normally.

Comment: I did not realise that WinRAR could extract the content of setup files.

Comment: I changed the extension of `setup.exe` to `setup.zip` and it worked out with FAR Manager I use... Maaaan...

Comment: The most obvious solution

Comment: Yes, it works! had to install a dependency of this old version on win10! Only winrar was able to uncompress the setup file, then I was able to install (run as Administrator).

Comment: How did you extracted files from setup.exe?

Comment: See the previous comments - there are a couple of ways.